# .htaccess 301 Redirect not working expectedly when URL have hypens and slashes

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect some old page url to new url. The domain is the same as I am moving from Joomla to WordPress platform.

May I know why some rules work and some don't when the path is longer?

These worked:

---

```
Redirect 301 /en/why-choose-us /en/start-here
Redirect 301 /en/products-services/ /en/services/
Redirect 301 /en/news-activity/news /en/news

www.domainname.com/en/why-choose-us 
will redirect to 
www.domainname.com/en/start-here
```

---

However, these don't work

---

```
Redirect 301 /en/products-services/category/product/ /en/services/product-a/
Redirect 301 /en/products-services/individual/product-b /en/services/product-b
Redirect 301 /en/products-services/category/product-c /en/services/product

www.domainname.com/en/products-services/category/product/
will redirect to 
www.domainname.com/en/services/category/product/  (and show 404 page not found)
```

---

Any idea why?

Thanks

Comment: Add your new redirect rules above previous rules.

Comment: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect: _“[…] any request **beginning with URL-path** will return a redirect request to the client at the location of the target URL. Additional path information beyond the matched URL-path will be appended to the target URL.”_ (highlight by me) - this directive does _prefix-based_ matching.

Comment: It looks like it although I found it difficult to understand. Can you show me the work around ?

Comment: Sorry for asking the answer as I am not a programmer. I just know the very basic to get simple stuff done. Thanks.